# Convergence of a complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have a question about this series:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{\sqrt{3} - i}{2} \right)^n
$$

How can I show whether the series converges or not?

The problem is that the root test and the ratio test don't work (limsup = 1). 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a geometric series with ratio $\frac{\sqrt3}2-i\frac12=\cos\frac{11\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{11\pi}6=e^{i11\pi/6}$ and it's clear that $|e^{i11\pi/6}|=1$ so the series does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

A series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q^n$ converges if and only if $|q|< 1$.
Thus it suffices to compute an absolute value.